# WebForms: CopyToAsync never terminates when UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext true

Tags: asp.net, webforms, async-await, .net-4.5.2

I've just started introducing async methods into an ASP.NET Web Forms application.

I have the following code...

```
using (Stream tempStream = File.Create(tmpFile))
{
    using (Stream docStream = await AttachmentOperations.OpenReadAsync(document.Attachment))
    {
        await docStream.CopyToAsync(tempStream);
    }
}
```

the OpenReadAsync has code which returns a file like so....

```
Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open);
return Task.FromResult(stream);
```

... the code works fine when I add the following setting to the appSettings...

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
```

However I actually need this setting to be true to enable access to the HttpContext within asynchronous calls.  With aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext set to true the call to  CopyToAsync never terminates, I have to kill the IISExpress process to unlock the file I'm attempting to copy.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?